# How can I write Spring XML about multiple inputs

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I am implementing mediation module.
This system sends many files to target systems with adding some information.

There are many input sources and output targets.
So, I want to write Spring XML for this process. But I cannot find this solution.

I saw some articles in Jboss community.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/apache_camel_development_guide/basicprinciples-multipleinputs

In this article, there is below definition of java dsl.

```
from("URI1").to("DestinationUri");
from("URI2").to("DestinationUri");
from("URI3").to("DestinationUri");
```

Is this code possible in springXML?
Please check my question and reply solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only have 1 from per route. Having 2+ is deprecated and not recommended. And in Camel 3 we have restricted this to exactly 1 input only.

So use 1 route per input. You can link multiple routes together via direct if you want to call something that is shared among those routes

```
from a
  to direct:shared

from b
  to direct:shared

from direct:shared
  to foo
```

Comment: Thank you. If we fetch multiple input directory, which component can we select?
I am using pollenrich component. Is using this component right?